# High speed, TTL compatible, high-side switch IC

Tags: mosfet, switches, driver, high-speed

I like full integrated automotive high-side switches, such as the ISP452. I like them because of their simplicity, making extremely easy driving grounded loads at standard voltages (12V or 24V) with limited current requirements (1A). I like them because of their robustness. The only big drawback that I see with these ICs is their limited switching frequency.

While most applications would work well at low PWMs, in the hundreds or few thousands of Hertz, some applications require to use frequencies outside the audible noise bandwidth (greater than 20 KHz). When linearization of the output signal is needed, typically with simple LC filters, a high frequency helps reducing the size of the inductor and capacitor.

My question is, why is it so hard to find high speed (>20KHz), TTL compatible (5V PWM drive), high-side switches?

I would not necessarily require an automotive classified chip, but is there any alternative?

Comment: There is a difference between a switch and PWM output. You can use discrete components like MOSFET driver IC + MOSFET + several protection features to get a high speed PWM stage.

Comment: I actually dont see any difference in a high side load switch, PWM driven. It's like the ISP452 and thousands of ICs like that. The only bottleneck is low switchig frequency. The reason I am searching for such component, it's because I want to avoid building my own circuit with discrete components

Comment: These switches are slow because the embedded NMOS gate drive voltage will usually be generated from an internal charge pump, which has a tiny output current. Fast switching needs a different architecture, with bootstrap capacitor usually...